# Call Google Translate from Python

Tags: python, ajax

I want to execute [this script (view source)](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/translate.html) that uses Google Translate AJAX API from python, and be able to pass arguments and get the answer back.  I don't care about the HTML.

I understand I need to embed a Javascript interpreter of some sort.  Does this mean I need to have a browser instance and manipulate it?  What is the cleanest way to access this API from python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [google-api-translate-python](http://googletranslate.sourceforge.net/) to talk to google api.

**EDIT:** It wasn't clear where the sources are, found them [here](https://googletranslate.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/googletranslate/src/trunk/).

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be a simplistic wrapper of the REST API, and works as a good example of how easy it in fact is to use. :)

Comment: That's why we love REST and JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the RESTful API instead. It's designed for environments that are not Javascript.

http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/reference.html#_intro_fonje

That should be easy to use from Python.

Answer (score 1):

Had to do this recently, and since I had to translate long strings, I couldn't use URL parameters, but rather use a data payload. Thought this is the best place to share this solution.
The trick basically is to use Python's excellent Requests module post, but since google require a GET request, use the 'X-HTTP-Method-Override' header to override the request method to GET.
(plainly using requests.get messes up the data payload)

the code:

```
import requests


def translate_es_to_en(text):
    url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2"
    data = {
        'key': '<your-server-google-api-key>'
        'source': 'es',
        'target': 'en',
        'q': text
    }
    headers = {'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'GET'}

    response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
    return response.json()
```

Hope this helps anyone still tackling this